# How to assign value for a variable from user input in python Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *

def userinput():
    v=StringVar()
    a=input(v.get)
    return(a)

sub = Tk()

Label(sub, text = "Your name :").grid(row=0)

num1 = Entry(sub)
num1.grid(row=0,column=1)

name2=userinput()

Button(sub, text="Proceed", command=sub.destroy).grid(row=1,column=3)


mainloop()
print name2
```

When I run this code i get the following in the shell:

(bound method StringVar.get of (tkinter.StringVar object at 0x02E48D30))

Answer (score 1):

I have a vague idea of what you're trying to do. First, don't use the `input` method with a GUI. Use the GUI. And here is how you can convert what you have to do at least that much. To operate it, type a name if the entry field, then press the `Return` key.

```
from tkinter import *
import sys


def userinput(*args):
    print(v.get())

sub = Tk()
v = StringVar()

Label(sub, text = "Your name :").grid(row=0)

num1 = Entry(sub, textvariable=v)
num1.grid(row=0,column=1)
num1.bind("<KeyPress-Return>", userinput)

userinput()

Button(sub, text="Proceed", command=sys.exit).grid(row=1,column=3)

sub.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for replying....Actually i want to assign the user input from num1 to variable name2 .. so that i can process the input